# Kafka Streams - Join two streams and get values ordered by date

Tags: join, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have two streams, both with the same key. **Stream1** values are temperatures and the **Stream2** values are types of events, "red" or "green". The key is "station".

```
KStream<String, String> Stream1 = builder.stream(inputTopic);
KStream<String, String> Stream2 = builder.stream(inputTopic2);
```

The idea is to join both of those streams and get their value by date order. For example, my producer sent the following records:

topic1: -35º (12:10:10) 
topic1: -40º (12:10:11) 
topic2: "red" (12:10:12) 
topic1: 20º (12:10:13) 
topic2: "green" (12:11:00) 
topic1: 10º (12:11:05) 
topic2: "red" (12:11:10) 
topic1: 40º (12:11:20)

I want to have a new stream with all those values in that same order. The goal is to associate the temperature with the previous type of event. For example, **20º (12:10:13) is a red type, 10º (12:11:05) is a green type and 40º (12:11:20) is a red type.**

How should I proceed?

Comment: Sounds great. Where is the join code you've tried? Maybe ksqlDB could help as well

Comment: Joins in Kafka Streams work on keys. Not sure what you mean by "both with the same key" -- you don't show keys in your example? -- For example, `20º (12:10:13`) can only join with `red` if both records have the same key...